# Respond to MINA request after aggregating several requests in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-mina

I'm trying to implement a mina service where the response to the final message should be based on the previous messages.  Each message (header (1), data (n), end (1)) should receive a response, but the response to the "end" message should be based on the "header", and any "data" messages received as well as the "end" message.  Currently, I'm routing the messages to an aggregator which completes when it finds a "header" and "end" message for a particular correlation id.  Unfortunately, the response is being sent before (or at the same time?) the message is sent to the aggregator, so I don't have access to the aggregated message (which contains all the data I need to build the correct response) when building the response.

Is there a way to do this without manually storing and accessing the accumulated data (that is, without re-implementing camel's aggregator)?

Edit:

Route is something like:

```
<camelContext>
    <route>
        <from uri="mina:..."/>
        <process ref="messageProcessor"/>
        <aggregate>
            <process ref="completeMessageProcessor"/>
        </aggregate>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I left out some tags and attributes (`correlationExpression`, `completionPredicate`, `strategyRef`, etc.) for clarity.

The messages were being aggregated properly, and they were being processed properly when "completed" (that is, when aggregated).  But the response sent back through the `mina` endpoint to the client was the one generated by the `messageProcessor`, never the one generated by the `completeMessageProcessor`.

For example (and yes, it's a rather contrived example, but bear with me), let's say the protocol involves the client sending a header message which includes the total number of data messages it expects to send.  Then it sends a number of data messages, which might be different in number to what it expected to send.  Finally, it sends a footer, or end, message.  The server should then respond back with the difference between the expected number of messages and the actual number of messages.  With the route as written, that is impossible, since the number of messages is not known by the `messageProcessor`, which only processes individual messages.  The `completeMessageProcessor`, having the aggregated message (consisting of header, all the data, and the end) **does** know this number, but the response generated at that point is not propagated back to the `mina` endpoint.

Changing the parsing of the messages to generate a message only when entire composed message is received is not an option, since the server must respond to the individual messages.

Comment: post your route...not sure what you mean by "the response is being sent before (or at the same time?) the message is sent to the aggregator..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

off the top, my guess is that the `messageProcessor` is setting up the OUT message, but the `completeMessageProcessor` is setting up the IN message.  The [mina](http://camel.apache.org/mina.html) consumer response is expecting/using the OUT message instead.

you can add some [logging](http://camel.apache.org/log.html) to verify this.  if this is the case, then you might change your `messageProcessor` to use the IN body instead (or use exchanges headers) and add a transform after your `completeMessageProcessor` to set the OUT body based on the IN body

```
<transform>
  <simple>${in.body}</simple>
</transform>
```

see this for more information: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

UPDATE: after some discussion, the real issue is that the aggregator currently only handles "InOnly" exchanges

Comment: This was exactly it. Thanks!  I'd been unwittingly depending on camel's default of propagating the IN message if no OUT message is set, and had been tripped by the fact that `<bean...>` processing sets the OUT message (rather than falling back on propagating the IN message).  So the `<bean...>` tags I'd been using before the aggregator were properly setting the OUT message, which is why I was getting a response there, but not after the aggregator.

Comment: awesome...glad I could help...I've done exactly that many times

Comment: Hrm. Apparently I was mistaken, it doesn't work.  The response being sent back is still the one calculated in `messageProcessor` and not the one in `completeMessageProcessor`, even though I'm explicitly setting the OUT message body there.  In fact, if I don't set the OUT message in `messageProcessor`, the response being sent back is `null`.

Comment: After investigating some more, it appears the AggregationStrategy does not receive the original Exchange, but rather a copy.  I can verify this by inspecting the exchange IDs at various points.  All through the chain, right up to just before the aggregator, the exchange ID remains the same.  The Exchange passed into the AggregationStrategy as the `newExchange`, though, has a different ID.  Given that, it's not surprising that the response being sent back to the mina endpoint is not the one generated by the aggregator, since that's on a different Exchange.  It looks like I'm out of luck. :(

Comment: I see your point, the Aggregator creates a new Exchange destined for a downstream endpoint, not as a response.  That said, I believe you can use the content enricher pattern along with a separate route for your aggregator to decorate the primary exchange with its result...

Comment: How would that work? A `wiretap` into the aggregator, output from the aggregator to a, say, `direct` endpoint, and `enrich` the exchange right after the `wiretap`? I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Meh, project priorities changed, so I had to stop work on this issue.  Before doing so, though, I was unable to use `enrich` or `pollEnrich` successfully in this way.  Basically, I couldn't figure out where to route the output from the aggregator in order to fetch it with `pollEnrich` (tried `direct` and `seda` endpoints, both blocked when trying to enrich). `enrich` didn't seem like a good match, because of its Producer mechanics (i.e. where would the route go from after the `<from uri="direct:enrich"/>`?).

Comment: after some digging I see the issue, the aggregator currently only handles "InOnly" exchanges...not sure of a way around it at this point

Comment: Well, I guess that's that. I'll mark it as answered again. Thank for taking the time to help with this!